# Transformation from ISO-8859-1 encoded XMl-File to UTF-8 in PHP

Tags: php, xml, encoding, simplexml

I have this XML-File:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="ISO-8859-1"  ?>
<Identifikation xmlns="http://www.ofd-hannover.la/Identifikation">
    <Version>2006-10</Version>
...
```

It contains German special chars like 'ÄÖß'. Currently I work with this piece of code:

```
    $strXml = file_get_contents('assets/file.xml');
    $strXml = iconv("ISO-8859-1","UTF-8",$strXml);
    $objXml = simplexml_load_string($strXml);
```

But the result is:

> AhornstraÃƒÂŸe instead of Ahornstraße

No matter if I insert into a UTF-8 MySql DB or simply echo in a HTML template with charset UTF-8.

Comment: Clearly `iconv()` is failing somehow. What platform are you on? How you tried to set the locale using `setlocale(LC_ALL, 'de_DE'); // *nix` or `setlocale(LC_ALL, 'german'); // windows`?

Comment: The app is running on a CentOS host. `echo (Locale::getDefault())` results in: `de-DE`

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Somehow it works now (Laravel Code snippet):

```
$strXml    = file_get_contents(Input::file('xmlfile'));
$objXml = simplexml_load_string($strXml);
```

Results in the correct output. I have no idea what was wrong...

Answer (score 1):

It looks like your text is getting double-decoded: you took UTF-8, interpreted it as ISO 8859-1, and then converted that to UTF-8, resulting in a mess sometimes called "mojibake".

In ISO 8859-1, the character ß would be the single byte `DF`; in Unicode, it is codepoint `U+00DF`, which in UTF-8 requires the two bytes `C3 9F`. Treating those bytes as separate ISO 8859-1 characters and encoding *them* would I think give what you have.

So it would seem the encoding in the header of the XML file is lying, and it is not in fact in ISO 8859-1 encoding. Either the whole file is in UTF-8, or it contains unvetted input from another source, some of which was actually UTF-8.

Comment: I changed the encoding in the XML-File to "UTF-8", but then simplexml:load throws an error:
`simplexml_load_string(): Entity: line 77: parser error : Input is not proper UTF-8, indicate encoding ! Bytes: 0xDF 0x65 0x3C 0x2F`